# Use dictionary in view filter when value is a list

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using a dictionary as a filter in a django view in the form of:

```
CI_table.objects.values(*report_fields).filter(**report_query_values)
```

The problem is that the dictionary has some values which are lists, and I get this error:
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

What I'm trying to do is to create the filter from request.POST, and some fields in the form have multiple values selected.
It may be a better way to do this, so any advice on doing it differently would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `__in` lookup to fields which have a list value:

```
def make_lookup(field, value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return '%s__in' % field, value
    return field, value

filter_lookups = dict(make_lookup(k, v) for k, v in
                                        report_query_values.items())

CI_table.objects.values(*report_fields).filter(**filter_lookups)
```

Comment: Thanks again, it seems to work. Need to adjust a couple of things to confirm I get data but looks good :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can handle this very easily using a simple check and converting the key to `__in` format if it is a list:

```
for key in report_query_values:
    if type(report_query_values[key]) == list:
        report_query_values[key + "__in"] = report_query_values[key]
        report_query_values.pop(key)
```

That way, if a particular key has multiple values, it gets converted into an `attribute__in` kind of format which is what you would have used normally.

Comment: Thanks mu, I'm using the previous answer but this one also looks good.